# gdalwarp and gdal_translate give different results

Tags: python-3.x, gdal

I tried splitting the dem into tiled areas

```
gdal.Warp(dst, src, options=gdal.WarpOptions(outputBounds=(minx, miny, maxx, maxy))
```

But this code was too slow, so I split the DEM using 'ReadRaster' and 'WriteRaster'

As a result, I got the same result as when I split the DEM with gdal_translate, but it is not the same as when I use gdalwarp

How can I get the same result as when I split the DEM with gdalwarp?